# How would I send a PUT request with the following information using AFNetWorking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking, put

This is what my server API document shows me to return a successful request.

`curl -X PUT -d {"questions":[{"type":"control_head"}]} "https://api.request.com/forms"`

`{"questions":[{"type":"control_head"}]}` this is the parameter.
`https://api.request.com/forms` this is the URL.

How can I handle this properly handle this using AFNetWorking? This is what I've got so far.

```
 NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.request.com/forms"];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

  [manager PUT:urlStr parameters:parameter success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    [operation setUserInfo:userinfo];

    SBJsonParser *jsonparser = [SBJsonParser new];
    id result = [jsonparser objectWithString:[operation responseString]];
    if ( self.delegate != nil && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:finishSelector] ) {
        [self.delegate performSelector:finishSelector withObject:result];
    }

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [operation setUserInfo:userinfo];
    if ( self.delegate != nil && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:failSelector] ) {
        [self.delegate performSelector:failSelector withObject:[operation error]];
    }
}];
```

I am not sure how to handle parameter correctly.

Comment: You don't need to create `SBJsonParser`, AFNetworking has already converted response data into the JSON `responseObject` passed into the block.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct an `NSDictionary` equivalent of your parameters with:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"questions": @[@{@"type": @"control_head"}]};
```

Just pass that into `PUT`, and it should work as expected.